# An array of R^2 values

Tags: python

I have a function which computes the R^2 value for a given set of x and y data with the degree specified:

```
import numpy as np

# Polynomial Regression
    def polyfit(x,y,degree):
    coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, degree)

# Polynomial Coefficients
    results = coeffs.tolist()
# r-squared
    p = np.poly1d(coeffs)
# fit values, and mean
    yhat = p(x)                         # or [p(z) for z in x]
    ybar = np.sum(y)/len(y)          # or sum(y)/len(y)
    ssreg = np.sum((yhat-ybar)**2)   # or sum([ (yihat - ybar)**2 for yihat in yhat])
    sstot = np.sum((y - ybar)**2)    # or sum([ (yi - ybar)**2 for yi in y])
    r2= ssreg / sstot

    results=r2

return results
```

I tried this function to a sample set of data:

```
x = np.arange(1,5)
y = np.arange(1,5)

print polyfit(x,y,1)

>>1.0
```

So far so good. My problem now is I want to vary the degree (the 3rd parameter for the polyfit function) by means of iteration. I'm thinking of using

```
n=np.linspace(1,9,100)
```

and for each value of n, I can get an r^2 value then store it to an array.

```
r2= [] #array for each r^2 value for each value of n in linspace
```

Can someone help me on this one? I'm new in python and I'm still having a hard time doing iterations.Thank you.

Comment: The degree must be an integer value -- it's the degree of the polynomial.  `numpy.linpace()` will give you floating point numbers which don't make much sense. I suggest using `range()` or `numpy.arange()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> array for each r^2 value for each value of n in linspace

You could write this as a list comprehension:

```
r2 = [polyfit(x, y, n) for n in np.linspace(1,9,100)]
```

Converting to a numpy array is not hard:

```
r2 = np.array(r2)
```